# Console View for AWS EC2 Windows Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, vmware-esxi, ocr

We are starting to move our infrastructure from VMware to AWS.  VMware allows you to open a console connection to the VM to see what on the screen without RDPing to it. It's basically like logging directly into the machine as if it were real and you were in front of it.

This is particularly useful for some of our internal applications that require a persistent session and do things like screen scraping and OCR. They also automatically generate keystrokes and mouse movements.

I was wondering if a console session like the one in VMware is possible in AWS. The only thing I've found remotely close to what might work is installing VNC on it which opens up other security risks so that really isn't an option.

Anyone run into this and have any thoughts?

FYI: Our machines are currently Windows 7 and server 2012

Answer (score 2):

AWS has the ability to capture a [screen shot](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-instance-console-screenshot/) of a running instance, perhaps this is what you are looking for? It does not allow you to interact with the host.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I was looking for some way to interact with the host that isn't RDP similar to the way VMware allows a console.  Didn't know about the screen shot though so thanks for that info

Comment: Unfortunately AWS doesn't provide a remote-console mechanism.